# Handling Access Token in URL after Google OAuth Login with Supabase in Nuxt 3

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, google-oauth, access-token, supabase

I am currently working on a Nuxt 3 application and have been trying to implement Google OAuth using Supabase for user authentication. I have set up Google as an authentication provider and it appears to work as expected: I'm able to see the Google login screen, and after successful login, I'm redirected back to my homepage.

However, I'm encountering an issue where the access token, instead of being stored as a cookie or in local storage, is appended in the URL like so (token shortened for brevity):

`http://localhost:3000/#access_token=eyJb<...>PZg0165&refresh_token=2OD<...>7A&token_type=bearer`

Upon successful redirection, the following warnings appear in the console:

```
Multiple GoTrueClient instances detected in the same browser context. It is not an error, but this should be avoided as it may produce undefined behavior when used concurrently under the same storage key.

[Vue Router warn]: The selector "#access_token=eyJhbGciO<...>PZg0165&refresh_token=2OODw0wgEx2Fp_Nn9VE7IA&token_type=bearer" is invalid. If you are using an id selector, make sure to escape it. You can find more information about escaping characters in selectors at https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes or use CSS.escape (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape).
```

When checking the Supabase Authentication User database, I can see the user has been added successfully, and the token looks correct when inspected on jwt.io.

Here is the relevant code snippet in my Nuxt 3 application:

```
 <script setup>
  const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
 
  const login = async () => {
    const { error } = supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: "google",
    });
 
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
</script>
 
<template>
  <h1>Log in</h1>
  <button> Login with Google </button>
</template>
```

My questions are:

- What could be the reason for this issue? Is this a bug within Supabase, or am I missing some configuration or step?
- Should I manually extract the access token from the URL and store it, or should Supabase handle this process automatically?
- If manual extraction is necessary, what would be the best practices for this in a Nuxt 3 application?

Any help or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to make sure to only have one Supabase client. This client will automatically read the access token from the URL and fire an `onAuthStateChange` event: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-onauthstatechange

Comment: As far as I know, I only have one Supabase client, since I only have 1 single "const supabase = useSupabaseClient()" instruction. I don't know what causes the "Multiple GoTrueClient instances detected" warning

Comment: Is your client initialisation maybe executed multiple times? Maybe try implementing a singleton pattern to make sure only one instance exists.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. I have sucessfully fixed both issues:

1. *"Multiple GoTrueClient instances detected ..."* → indeed I had 2 components loaded on the same page with a `const supabase = useSupabaseClient()`. I removed one and the warning disappeared.
2. *"The selector "#access_token=..."* →  I contacted Supabase support and they instructed me to install the new version of GoTrue (version ^2.46.1) which is a package within supabase related to authentication → `npm install @supabase/gotrue-js@v2.46.1`. I installed it and the call back url is now clean, and cookies sucessfully created